# how to NOT update a field Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, controller, validation

I'm a newbie in rails. how put a validated on password field. specified only on create and used an allow_blank method. but everytime i update it still creates a nil in the password field. any help?

```
validates :password, :presence => { :on => :create },
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length => { :within => 8..40},
                     :allow_blank => true,
```

Comment: Do you have a :default => nil in your schema.rb (or migrations)?

Comment: You might want to post the code you are using to create the record you're talking about. Also, what is your intention? You want a non-nil blank string in the db?

Comment: i was trying to figure out how to update a profile without changing its password. i figured out my problem. turns out the code above was correct. but it was still encrypting my confirm password field and just making a mess. so i had to put an encrypt_password if password changed code. sorry if this sounds like garbage to you. i'm used to system languages like C. so you can understand how ruby would blind side me

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
validates :password, :presence => { :if => :new_record? },
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length => { :within => 8..40 }
```